# Setting background image to button in fxml css leaving an offset in left and right

Tags: java, css, javafx-8, fxml

I have a set of buttons in fxml having class name `submenuButton`. I want to add a common background image to these buttons using css. I tried the following:

```
.submenuButton{
    -fx-min-width: 25px;
    -fx-pref-height: 25px;
    -fx-pref-width: auto;
    -fx-background-image:url(images/but-up-center.png); 
    -fx-background-position: 5px 0px;
    -fx-background-repeat:repeat-x;
    -fx-background-size: stretch;
}
```

This sets the button image leaving 5px from the left and extends to the end of the button. But I want to have this image ended at 5px from the right also.

So, could anybody suggest what can be done in the css so that it leaves 5px space both on the left and the right.